# Does sprockets mixin raw .js files or just coffeescript files?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3.1, coffeescript, sprockets, rails-3.1

Does the sprocket functionality only mixin .js.coffee files to the application.js or will it also add raw .js files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both. [Read the docs](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets), particularly under the heading "Using Engines."